# Time zone issue in displaying records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I have vehicle model in my rails application. It has three columns named 'arrival_date', 'arrival_time' and 'parking_address'. A person can not park vehicle more than 4 hours at a parking slot. I want to display all future parkings and parkings for today. But for today it should display all the vehicles which are currently parked or gonna park. Below logic might clear you what I am trying to say,

```
 <% if (vehicle.arrival_date == Date.current)%>
    <% if Time.now < (vehicle.arrival_time + 4.hours) %>
       <%= vehicle.arrival_time %>
    <% end %>
 <% else %>
    <%= vehicle.arrival_time %>
 <% end %>
```

The above code will display all the vehicles which are gonna parked in future dates.The logic and everything works fine but I am not able to figure out timezone issue. I am storing 'arrival_time' in UTC format on my server and also created_at is stored as a UTC time. When my client from USA(Pacific Standard Time) tries to access /vehicles it does not lists vehicles. With the help of 'parking_address' I am able to get zone. Afterwards I changed my code to below lines,

```
a = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode property.address
lat_long_arr = a.ll.split(',').flatten
unless lat_long_arr.blank?
Timezone::Lookup.config(:geonames) do |c|
  c.username = 'xyz'
  c.offset_etc_zones = true
end
timezone = Timezone.lookup(lat_long_arr[0], lat_long_arr[1])
<% if (vehicle.arrival_date.in_time_zone(timezone)) == Date.current.in_time_zone(timezone))%>
   <% if Time.now.in_time_zone(timezone) < (vehicle.arrival_time.in_time_zone(timezone) + 4.hours)) %>
      <%= vehicle.arrival_time %>
   <% end %>
<% else %>
    <%= vehicle.arrival_time %>     
<% end %>
```

Still it does not work for me. I can see right results in India. I also do not want to get zone based on users computer I am assuming that user is accessing it from the zone of 'parking_address'.

Comment: if your application is country specific you can set the default time zone in application.rb file , so there will be no time conflict.

Comment: Yes! It is being used by US people  only. I tried that too. I set my time to "Pacific timezone". Then I also tried it with "Central timezone". There are 5-6 timezones in USA and it has differences in times. But this did not work for me. Client said that I am not viewing any of the vehicles.

Comment: Some people suggested not to set timezone in application.rb. Rather store time in UTC only.

Comment: yes. right . give me few moments